# How to create a map[string] [2]int in Go?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go

I want to create a `map[string][2]int` in Go. I tried [this](https://play.golang.org/p/tV92Tc4QcN) at go playground but I got errors. How can I solve this?

```
fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
m:= make(map [string][2]int)
m["hi"]={2,3}
m["heello"][1]=1
m["hi"][0]=m["hi"][0]+1
m["h"][1]=m["h"][1]+1
fmt.Println(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your map initialization is correct.
You just need to explicitly declare the type of your map element:

```
m:= make(map [string][2]int)
m["test"] = [2]int{1,3}
fmt.Println(m)
```

This approach work if you don't need to access underlying elements.

If you need this, you have to use pointers:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    m := make(map[string]*[2]int)
    m["hi"] = &[2]int{2, 3}
    m["heello"] = &[2]int{0, 1}
    m["hi"][0] = m["hi"][0] + 1
    // commented out. Initialize it first
    //m["h"][1]=m["h"][1]+1
    fmt.Println(m) // 2 address
    fmt.Println(m["hi"], m["heello"])
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to assign to assign values to underlying arrays then. If that's what you need, you need to create a map of pointers.

Comment: @nessuno thank you, this solves the first problem at line 10 but I need to solve the rest also, I need to access a specific value of the array and then add to it , any solution?

Comment: I updated my answer following @Nebril hint

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a map of pointers to array if you want to be able to assign values to array indices. Check out this code (you need to initiate all map keys before using them as array though).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Assign(m map[string]*[2]int, key string, index int, value int) {
    if _, ok := m[key]; !ok {
        m[key] = &[2]int{}
    }

    m[key][index] = value
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    m := make(map[string]*[2]int)

    m["hi"] = &[2]int{2, 3}
    m["h"] = &[2]int{4, 5}

    //existing key
    Assign(m, "h", 1, 4)
    //new key
    Assign(m, "howdy", 1, 3)

    fmt.Println(m["hi"])
    fmt.Println(m["h"])
    fmt.Println(m["howdy"])

}
```

Comment: thank you but I need to add values without defining the key for example, if m["hi"] [0]=m["hi"][0]+1 and if m["hi"][0] is not created then it automatically be set to the default value which is 0 then m["hi"][0]=1

Comment: @SaidSaifi You can wrap the assignment in function which will check for the key and create new array if needed. Updated the code above to do that.

Answer (score 0):

See this issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3117

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    m := make(map[string][2]int)

    m["hi"] = [2]int{2, 3}

    m["heello"] = [2]int{}

    var tmp = m["heello"]
    tmp[1] = 1
    m["heello"] = tmp

    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

Comment: thank you but I don't want to define my keys always I want to use them as their default value if they don't exist for example if m["hi"] [0]=m["hi"][0]+1 and if m["hi"][0] is not created then it automatically be set to the default value which is 0 then m["hi"][0]=1